# Нужен Optional параметр в теле запроса FastApi,

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

У меня работает это с Pydantic, но без него никак, а писать для каждой функции модель, как будто бы не правильно, ибо у меня по 1-2 параметра.

1. Example with Pydantic

   ```
   class MyId(BaseModel):
       _id: Optional[str] = Field(...)

   @awaitable
   @router_get.post('/some')
   async def some_functon(*,
                          myId: myId
                          ):
   ```
2. Without Pydantic

   ```
   @awaitable
   @router_get.post('/some')
   async def some_functon(*,
                          _id: Optional[str] = Body(None, ebmed=True)
                          ):
   ```
3. Without Pydantic

   ```
   @awaitable
   @router_get.post('/some')
   async def some_functon(*,
                          _id: Optional[str] = Body(..., ebmed=True)
                         ):
   ```

Суть в том, что

Запрос для первого варианта `requests.post(url=url, json={"_id": None})`.

И

Запрос для первого `requests.post(url=url, json={})`.

Работают так, как мне надо, а именно второй вариант выдает ошибку, а первый работает.

Третий работает не так, как мне надо, ведь при запросе `json={}` он отрабатывает. как будто бы я подал `json={"_id": None}`.

Второй на запрос `json={"_id": None}` отдает "value_error.missing"

Comment: Если просто один параметр нужно передать, не проще url параметры использовать? `Работают так, как мне надо, а именно второй вариант выдает ошибку, а первый работает.` - работает именно потому, что в pydantic встроена валидация. Если нужно без pydantic, делайте вручную проверку, что `_id != None`, и кидайте исключение, если это не так (валидация вручную, по сути).

Comment: А, ну еще Optional предполагает, что значение может быть None, пробовали делать без Optional, т.е. что-то типа `_id: str = Body(..., ebmed=True)`?

Comment: @insolor, Отвечаю по порядку. Нужны именно post запросы из соображений безопасности. Параметр должен быть вставлен, но он может быть None, то есть _id != None не даст мне никакой информации о том, подали ли мне или нет этот параметр, ну и у меня 100+ методов и проверять в каждом кажется не лучшей затеей, даже если обойтись каким-то универсальным декоратором.  Если сделать так, как вы показали в последнем варианта, None не даст. 
В последнем случае параметр не сможет быть None